# Cast to a 32 bit integer may result in truncation PHP Propel?

Tags: php, int, propel

Looking at the source code of Propel (the PHP ORM library), I have found this method inside the propel/propel1/runtime/lib/query/Criteria.php file:

```
  /**
     * Set offset.
     *
     * @param int $offset An int with the value for offset.  (Note this values is
     *                    cast to a 32bit integer and may result in truncation)
     *
     * @return Criteria Modified Criteria object (for fluent API)
     */
    public function setOffset($offset)
    {
        $this->offset = (int) $offset;

        return $this;
    }
```

Why in the doc comments they say that the value casted to int may result in truncation??? Isn't the int kept to e.g. `4000000000` in 64 bit environment? Actually, it is, so why this "Note"?

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: not all PHP installs are 64bit, after all. On a 32bit PHP install, an int will max out at 2^31-1.

Comment: @MarcB I know, but if you read the documentation, it seems that they are assuming that the same goes for 64 bit, and it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum and minimum size of integer depends of the build of PHP : 32 or 64 Bits (operating system and processor must also follow)

For **PHP 32-Bits** the range is between ]**-2147483648**, **2147483647**[
For **PHP 64-Bits** the range is between ]**-9223372036854775808**, **9223372036854775807**[

My Test (**PHP 32-Bits, WINDOWS 7 64-Bits, Intel CORE i3 64-Bits**) :

```
<?php
$i = (int)2147483647;
var_dump($i);
```

Will ouput :

```
int(2147483647)
```

2nd test (just increment by 1 the last value)

```
<?php
    $i = (int)2147483647;
    var_dump($i);
```

Will ouput :

```
int(-2147483648)
```

Finally : to be sure about the max value of integer in your environment, just print this

```
var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX);
```