# How can I see if my XAMPP is running 32 bit or 64 bit?

Tags: php, xampp

I have tried going into PHPInfo but there is nothing that tells me if it's 64 bit or 32 bit. What is the easiest way to tell this?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: Windows 8. Windows. Not Linux.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<strike>If you're running windows, XAMPP is running a 32bit version of php, no matter of the installer's architecture.</strike>

**UPDATE 10/23/2019**
It would appear that since the latest build (Sep 24 2019)
Xampp now serves x64 by default and not x32

You can check your version by running php -v and reading the build date & architecture

Comment: Really? So none of the XAMPPs are 64 bit? So to get 64 bit you must use WAMPP?

Comment: @coderama You can always downloads the components separately

Answer (score 4):

You can use this command on your cmd - `D:\InstalledSoftware\xampp\apache\bin\httpd -v` 
Find your xampp folder then type this- `\apache\bin\httpd -v`

For More Details- https://superuser.com/questions/791887/apache-version-in-xampp/1091133

Answer (score 2):

May be is a trick, but it lets you know if your are running **PHP** on **32Bits** or **64Bits**, you have just to print the `PHP_INT_MAX` constant.
This is  a related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27949902/4098311

Answer (score 2):

Since you're on Windows there is no 64bit version of XAMPP. See here: https://www.apachefriends.org/de/download.html

[image]

If you want 64bit software you would have to search for the single components with 64bit

Answer (score 2):

just use `php -v`, this will output x64 or x32

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It shows x84 in my case and i have a Windows version 64bit. Thats pretty weird. On website is shown 64 bit. the Installer Button shows 64x.
The Filename contains 64bit...But he installs 32 bit... Thats pretty bad made...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34423652)